# Windows Context Menu & Batch -> edit selected file

Tags: windows, batch-file, contextmenu

I have a batch file which is supposed to work like this:

- Search for a specific txt file
- If text is found delete the line that contains the text
- If there are 2 or more spaces convertem them to 1 space
- Change file extension to a specific one

Basicaly I edit a file generated by difrent programs and convert it so that my own program can read it. (that means it has different names and extensions each time)

I create a new txt file and copy & paste from the original file to the txt file then run the batch file.

I want to skip the part where I make the new file and add the batch file to windows context menu so I can right-click on the original file and convert the file. But I dont know how to set the original file as the one to edit.

(Also I need to run this on windows XP)

Curent code:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

::Create txt file
set "fisiertxt=%CD%\New Text File.txt"
if not exist "%fisiertxt%" REM. > "New Text File.txt"

::Start txt file
start notepad "New Text File.txt"

::check if file is still open
:verifica
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq Notepad.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "Notepad.exe" >NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" goto Aici 
goto verifica

::Delete file if its empty
:Aici

>nul findstr "^" "New Text File.txt" || del "New Text File.txt"

:: check if there are delimitators delete them
find /c "99999 0 0 0" "New Text File.txt"
if "%ERRORLEVELs%"=="1" goto FaraSeparator
pause

:: if yes make a new file winought them


set count=1
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('find /V /I "99999 0 0 0" "New Text File.txt"') do (
    if !count!==1 echo.>document.txt
    if !count! GTR 1 echo %%A>>document.txt
    set /A count=!count!+1)



::
:: delete the exit file
:: delete the first row (the exit file has an emplty first row)
:: replace 2 or more spaces with 1 space
::

DEL Drumuire.mnu   2>nul /F /Q
:: replace with ->
SET delim= 
:: set number of lines to delete 
FOR /f "skip=1delims=" %%i IN (document.txt) DO (
    SET line=%%i
    (SET newline=)
    SET count=0
    CALL :SCHIMBARI
)

GOTO :eof

:SCHIMBARI
SET c1=%line:~0,1%
SET line=%line:~1%
IF "%c1%"==" " (SET /a count+=1) ELSE (
    IF %count%==0 (SET newline=%newline%%c1%) ELSE (
        IF %count%==1 (SET newline=%newline% %c1%) ELSE (
            SET newline=%newline%%delim%%c1%)
    SET count=0
    )
)
IF DEFINED line GOTO SCHIMBARI
::
:: You may want to preserve trailing spaces
:: or convert them...
::
IF %count%==0 GOTO SCOATE
IF %count%==1 SET newline=%newline% &GOTO SCOATE
SET newline=%newline%%delim%
:SCOATE
>>Drumuire.mnu ECHO %newline%
DEL document.txt
goto done
:: 
:: --------------------------------------------------------------------------
::


:winought delimitator
DEL Drumuire.mnu   2>nul /F /Q
:: replace with ->
SET delim= 
:: set number of lines to delete 
FOR /f "usebackq delims=" %%i IN ("New Text File.txt") DO (
    SET line=%%i
    (SET newline=)
    SET count=0
    CALL :PRESCHIMBA
)

GOTO :eof

:PRESCHIMBA
SET c1=%line:~0,1%
SET line=%line:~1%
IF "%c1%"==" " (SET /a count+=1) ELSE (
    IF %count%==0 (SET newline=%newline%%c1%) ELSE (
        IF %count%==1 (SET newline=%newline% %c1%) ELSE (
            SET newline=%newline%%delim%%c1%)
    SET count=0
    )
)
IF DEFINED line GOTO PRESCHIMBA
::
:: You may want to preserve trailing spaces
:: or convert them...
::
IF %count%==0 GOTO PRINT
IF %count%==1 SET newline=%newline% &GOTO PRINT
SET newline=%newline%%delim%
:PRINT
>>Drumuire.mnu ECHO %newline%


:done
```

Comment: That does not look anything like code that will run in a batch file. You are basically posting pseudo code. If you want help then post the code you are using.

Comment: Ive added my code, and also found out that there is an error if the txt contains qoutes, there shoudnt be a problem but just i case I should add I note :/

Comment: you can put your batchfile (or a link) to `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\`. Then right-click the file, select `Send To'  and select your script or link. Inside the script you can reference the file as `%1`

Comment: (not sure, if there is `%appdata%` on XP. Check, where the "SendTo" folder resides)

Comment: on xp the location is on ``C:\Documents and Settings\--MY Username--\SendTo`` . And its also hiden .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Stephan mentioned in the comments, you can accomplish your goal using the following steps.

1: Write batch file using parameters/arguments ([docs](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html))

> **context.bat**
>
> ```
> @echo off
> rem set up a couple variables for easier modification
> set "tfile=New Text File.txt"
> set "searchstring=9999"
>
> rem output some things for information purposes
> echo Source File: %1
> echo Target File: %tfile%
> echo Target Folder: %cd%
>
> rem copy the file
> echo Copying file...
> copy %1 "%tfile%"
>
> rem check for the search string defined above
> echo Checking for search string...
> find /c "%searchstring%" "%tfile%" >NUL
> if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" GOTO FOUNDSTRING
> if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" GOTO NOTFOUND
>
> :NOTFOUND
> echo Did not find search string (%searchstring%)
> GOTO ENDER
>
> :FOUNDSTRING
> echo Found search string (%searchstring%)
> GOTO ENDER
>
> :ENDER
> rem remove the next line once everything is working so you don't have to press a key each time it runs
> pause
> ```

2: Add to Windows "Send To":

```
copy context.bat %appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo
```

3: Right click, send to > context.bat, Profit!

> ```
> You targeted D:\test\test.txt!
> Press any key to continue . . .
> ```

Comment: Well this sure works on Win10 , and it skiped regedit. Im gona test it later on this day with XP sp3 , hoping it works.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that drag and drop will work too.  You can drag your target file onto the batch file.  This may be better depending on your workflow.

Comment: Somehow I faild to make it work on XP. Ive tried to do this: ``copy "%1" "New Text File.txt"
find /c "99999 0 0 0" "New Text File.txt"``( Im trying to make this as simple as posible because the people that will use this "can't" delete lines that contain "99999 0 0 0" and delete all the extra spaces.)

Comment: ``echo off

copy "%1" "New Text File.txt"
pause``    will give me this ``C:\Documents and settings\XPMUser>echo off
The system cannot find the file specified.
Press any key to continue . . .``
and winought qoutes I will get ``C:\Documents and settings\XPMUser>echo off
1 file<s> copied.
Press any key to continue...`` but the file is copied on ``C:\Documents and Settings\XPMUser``

Comment: You are missing the `@` symbol.  You can actually completely remove that line if you would like.

Comment: or can I integrate the %1 in ``find /c "99999 0 0 0" %1`` somehow?

Comment: I made significant changes to the batch file in my answer. I included lots of comments (REM lines).  Please let me know if it helps.  Since this question is technically about using the right-click context menu and that is working, you may want to ask a new question for additional troubleshooting.

Comment: Background info:"Sent To" as well as "Drag'n Drop" will already add quotes if needed. If you want to be explicit, use `"%~1"` (the tilde `~` removes surrounding quotes from the parameter if there are such). Just `"%1"` might put another pair of (useless and malicious) quotes around  a (maybe) already quoted string..

Comment: Ok , so I found out that ``%CD%``  on WINDOWS XP will take me to ``C:\Documents and settings\USER`` how can I get around it?

Comment: It should be wherever the batch file is located, or the current context.  YOu might want to add a `%tpath%` variable for your desired output path and then copy to `%tpath%/%tfile%` or similar.